# How to remove the default text "Please fill out this field"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have an input field

i need to remove the default text  **Please fill out this field**
i set the title as empty using jQuery function

```
$('#Form input[type=text]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('title', ' ');
});
```

It works fine except IE and Safari.

Then i tried **novalidate** but this only works if input field is inside the form

Here is my sample code

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>


.div2 .grp {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 2%;
    margin-bottom: 31px !important;
    line-height: normal !important;
}

.div2 input {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0 !important;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
    background: transparent!important;
}

.div2 label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    transition: .2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease all;
    color:Black;
}

.div1 {
    width: 14%;
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
   }


label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

       <div class="div1" >
            <div class='div2'>
                <div class="grp" id="divFirstName">      
                <input type="text" runat="server" id="TB_TestForm" onclick="TestForm()"  onblur="TestForm()" required/>
                <label>My first name<span class="reqstar">*</span></label>
                <span class="required"></span>
            </div>

       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function TestForm() {
        var html = document.getElementById("divFirstName").style.position;
        if (html == "relative" || html=="") {
            document.getElementById("divFirstName").style.position = "inherit";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("divFirstName").style.position = "relative";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help

Comment: Show the HTML of the input field. I assume you're using a `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: please show us your html markup, also make sure that you are setting the inputs to an empty string `""` and not a whitespace `" "` like you are doing above

Comment: `It works fine except IE and Safari.` So what about browsers cache?!...  Anyway, you should use `$('#Form input[type=text][title]').removeAttr('title');`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code **necessary to reproduce** it in the question itself.  Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: I cant use placeholder or title attribute and  my input field is like this                                                                         <input type="text" runat="server"  id="Tb_test"  required/>

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML element use `placeholder` attribute you can use the following code (vanilla JS jQuery is not required):

```js
document.getElementById('input').placeholder = '';
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

Notes: Please provide your HTML so we can figure out ad-hoc solution for you.

Comment: That's for sure wrong because OP said it works on browsers `except IE and Safari`...

Comment: @Ted Hence the 'If' at the start... (I agree with you, needs clarifying first)

Comment: @freedomn-m - should be a comment

Comment: @GibboK i have tried this code.. but it won't work in my code. My input field have some style functions. if i am using placeholder or title attribute my style wont works proberly. so i am using simple html <input type="text" runat="server" id="Tb_test" required/>

Comment: @Roshmi please post your html :)